XslxWriter returns zero to formulas (not even in the formula bar)
I tried writing formulas with xlsxWriter and the
worksheet.write_formula but in my excel I only have zero.
Datas are put in columns A and C but then the following formula returns a zero when I open the xlsx file with the official Excel app.
worksheet.write(0,3, '=INDEX(C:C;MATCH(MINIFS(A:A;A:A;">="&EDATE(A5;1));A:A)

I have imported what’s necessary ant tried everything I found on internet (adding '' at the end, adding _xlfn. at the beginning…)

There are a couple of issues here. The first is that the formula should be using comma instead of semi-colon see the XlsxWriter docs on Non US Excel functions and syntax. Also MINIFS() is a future function so it needs to be prefixed like this _xlfn.MINIFS(), see the docs on Formulas added in Excel 2010 and later.
With these changes the formula should work:
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("example.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


# Some sample data.
worksheet.write(4, 0, 0)

worksheet.write(0, 3, '=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(_xlfn.MINIFS(A:A,A:A,">="&EDATE(A5,1)),A:A))')

workbook.close()


Output:

You can also use the 'use_future_functions' constructor option to automatically escape future functions:
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("example.xlsx", {'use_future_functions': True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


# Some sample data.
worksheet.write(4, 0, 0)

worksheet.write(0, 3, '=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(MINIFS(A:A,A:A,">="&EDATE(A5,1)),A:A))')

workbook.close()

